# Meson masses difference

Tags: group-theory, quantum-chromodynamics, mesons

I am reading some group theory applied to QCD and they show how by using the lightest 3 quarks in the $l=0$ state we get 9 pseudoscalar mesons and 9 vector mesons. The difference in masses between the 2 classes is explained by the existence of a spin-spin interaction, which seems like a reasonable argument. However they don't say anything about the fact that the mass of the singlet in each case (the 9 mesons are grouped in an octet and a singlet) is significantly higher than the masses of the mesons in the octet. What is the reason for that? Thank you!

Comment: What does this have to do with muons? Was that a typo in your title?

Comment: It's complicated. The octet of pseudoscalars have smaller than normal mass, due to chiral symmetry breaking, but the singlet is exempt, as its symmetry is anomalous. For the vector mesons, *nobody* is a singlet: the singlet has mixed with the isosinglet octet member to yield two hybrid states, ω and  φ, whose masses reflect the $s\bar s$ content more than anything else.  There is a lot of misleading dross published in vector meson perorations...

Answer (score 2):

The reason, why $\eta^{'}$ meson is significnatly heavier, that than the mesons in the octet is rather nontrivial and a interesting story, known as $\eta-\eta^{'}$ **puzzle**.

It is resolved by 't Hooft instanton mechanism https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.37.8, whose ​$\frac{1}{N}$ realization is also known as the **Witten–Veneziano** mechanism http://cds.cern.ch/record/133349.

The mass of $\eta^{'}$ is so large due to the $U_A(1)$ **axial anomaly**.